# Can sign of integration by parts equation be changed to negative?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Integration by parts:

$$\int u \:dv+\int v \: du=uv$$

Are there any circumstances under which the sign can be changed so that the following is true?

$$\int u \:dv-\int v \: du=uv$$

Comment: If $\int v\: du=0$.

Comment: I wish.  I could have solved any number of famous unsolved problems if I could have done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\bullet$ For definite integrals, this is true if $\int_a^b v(t)u'(t) dt=0$

Example in $[-1,1]$ if we put $v(t)=t^2+1$ and  $u(t)=\ln(t^2+1)$ then :
$$[u(t)v(t)]_{-1}^1=0$$
and :$$\int_{-1}^1udv-\int_{-1}^1 v du =  \int_{-1}^1 2t \ln(t^2+1)dt-\int_{-1}^12tdt = 0 $$since  $t \mapsto t \ln(t^2+1)$ and  $t\mapsto 2t$  are odd one $[-1,1]$

$\bullet$ For indefinite integrals it's true only  if $v=0$  or $u$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement is true if you have a definite integral and interchange the limits for the second integral, otherwise you cannot just change the signs.